# Noise removel in laidar data

Tags: gis, arcgis, point-cloud-library, lidar, liblas

I have a Lidar data in .las file and i want to remove Noise from IT ?
 is this is possible in open sources tools i.e las tool ,LibLas  or any other open source , 
Because my finding are we can achieve this in point cloud library using .pcd file format But can we do same in Lib las or las tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear, from the question, if you need to perform noise removal programmatically or through a tool. Let's try to break down your problem anyway. The point-cloud-library has a nice set of features to perform noise reduction and removal. However, as you noticed, it mainly works on `pcl` files. You have a couple of options to convert your `las` files to `pcl`:

1. You can add [this set](https://github.com/adasta/pcl_io_extra) of readers to your PCL-based project. The [LAS reader](https://github.com/adasta/pcl_io_extra/blob/master/src/las_io.cpp) seems to be able to read las files.
2. You can use the [PDAL toolchain](http://pdal.io/), and do something like `pdal translate original.las output.pcd`.

For the noise removal part you also have a couple of options, once you have the files: you can either either use one of the many noise removal filters from PCL (see [here](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group__filters.html) and [here](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/remove_outliers.php), e.g. `StatisticalOutlierRemoval`) by calling the related classes in your code, or simply use the PDAL processing pipeline from the command line to further clean your data, as described in [one](https://www.pdal.io/workshop/exercises/analysis/denoising/denoising.html) of their tutorials.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion, further i also want to generate contours, is it possible using PDAL? or could you suggest any other open-source library for contour generation.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can use pdal for that, but I'm sure you can use PCL. See, for example, [here](http://www.pcl-users.org/Getting-the-contour-of-cluster-indices-td4020509.html). Also, if my answer was useful, please consider accepting it.

Comment: Yes Thanks Mr Dexter . And Yes i try to accept but i am not able to accept because  When i try to accept Its Says 

" Thanks for feedback but need reputation  =15" Sorry But  in  future i will surely accept this Answers so Cheers